# How to get two values from select tag

Tags: php, forms, post, explode

I've been running some code where it returns the id and now I need the id and name returned. I feel like this should be extremely easy but I've having a difficult time doing it. I tried to explode the values and still cannot get the $name to work.

Code:

```
 <select name="id" required="true" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
   <?php                         
     $row="SELECT id, name FROM modules";
     while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
     echo "<option value=\"" . $row['id'] . "\">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
     }

       list($id,$name) = explode(".",$_GET['id']);
       echo $name;
   ?>
 </select>
```

I'd like to be able to get the id and the name both from the drop down menu if possible to POST.

Comment: Only `name` gets posted. Why do you want it anyway? Also, `select` doesn't have `value` attribute, options do.

Comment: You have to put all data you need on the `value` attribute with some separator like `|` or `-` and then do the `explode` with this separator to get them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this way:

```
<select name="id" required="true" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
   <?php                         
     $row="SELECT id, name FROM modules";
     while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
     echo "<option value=\"" . $row['id'] . '|' . $row['name'] . "\">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
     }
   ?>
 </select>
```

And then:

```
list($id,$name) = explode("|",$_GET['id']);
echo $name;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working. I still get that the $name is undefined but where it list the ID it's listing ID|Name. Is there somewhere specifically I have to put the list? Can I put it inside of the </select> tags or must it be outside. I'm sorry and thanks a ton!

Comment: I got it to work just had to change the GET to a POST and it worked fine. Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

HTML forms will send the **value** of a select box (in this case it's your `$row['id']`) but not the display text (in your case `$row['name']`).

If you don't specify a value, the display text will be posted. If you want both, you'll probably have to use Javascript to assign the display text to a hidden field when it's selected, which will be posted as well.

Here's a jQuery example:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id').change(function() {
        var display_text = $( "#id option:selected" ).text();
        $('#hidden_field').val(display_text);
    });
});
</script>

<select name="id" required="true" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
... etc

<input type="hidden" name="hidden_field" id="hidden_field">
```

This example should assign the selected option's display text to `#hidden_field` which will be posted with the rest of your form, so then in PHP:

```
<?php

$selected_value = $_POST['id'];
$selected_display = $_POST['hidden_field'];

?>
```

Comment: `value` attribute is for `<option<>` tag, not `<select>`. Also, use jQuery to do this is not the best solution...

Comment: Thanks, updated. I agree that using jQuery where not necessary is not good practice, but is it better to do this or corrupt your data by concatenating values together?

Comment: `[value]|[display]` is not as clean as receiving `[value]` and `[display]`

Comment: Well, as far as HTTP does not allow you to pass well structured data to the server, I can't see this as a corruption.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to include both the id and the name in the value attribute of your option tag, delimited by some character (possibly a '.' if you are confident that the name and id will never contain a period).

Comment: The `value` is on the `option` tag, not on the `select`.

Comment: Err, my bad on that. Fixed.